# how to validate all inputs by class name using jquery don't want to use any plugin like validate

Tags: jquery

i want to validate all inputs using class name i'm using following code

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function() {

           $('input.inputme[type=hidden]').each(function () {

                 if($(this).val()==''){
                     choclates='false';
                 }else{
                      choclates='true';
                     }                      
            });
         if(choclates=='true'){
                  $('#choclateform').submit();
                 }else{
                 alert("Please Fill all Boxes.");
                 }

        });
```

when i posted this question code was different and was not working full but this works but i think i'm making it complicated can someone make it better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to prevent a form from being submitted, I'd hook the `submit` event on the form instead, and return `false` from *that* handler when blank fields are found (to prevent the form being submitted).

```
// Hook the submit event
$('#theForm').submit(function() {
    // Assume all will be fine
    var valid = true;

    // Check your inputs
    $('input.inputme[type=text]').each(function () {

        // Is this input's value (effectively) blank? Note that
        // there's no reason whatsoever to use $(this).val(),
        // with text fields this.value gives you the same thing
        // more efficiently.
        // I'm also trimming off whitespace and using the fact
        // that empty strings are "falsey".
        if (!$.trim(this.value)) {
            // Bug user
            alert("Please fill all boxes");

            // Flag that there was a problem
            valid = false;

            // Optionally, stop the `each` loop. If
            // you're *literally* going to use `alert`,
            // then I'd stop the loop or you'll irritate
            // people. But if you're showing some kind
            // of indicator next to the field instead,
            // then I'd leave this off and continue to do
            // all fields.
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (!valid) {
        // Cancel submission
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: @t-j-crowder thank you very much for the answer with comments i appreciate it, i just updated my question can you please comments on it or post new answer ?

Comment: @Yasir: You shouldn't *completely* change a question like that when people have already answered the original question. Instead, post a separate question.

Comment: alert needs to be moved in if(!valid statement

Comment: @Yasir: It doesn't *need* to, not the way I've written it. But moving it would be harmless. Are you going to revert the question to its original form?

Comment: Sorry for changing my question but the question logic was same and @T.J you write the better code when i was writing the same :) i dont' need else statement in if empty.

Comment: using your way i will not get 3,4 alerts that boxes are empty ?

Comment: @Yasir: Read the comments in the code, I make it clear that no, you won't get multiple alerts if you return `false` out of the `each` function (see [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/)).

Answer (score 0):

this may be thrown by white-spaces! isn't it? check this too:

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function() {
    var flag = true;
    $('input.inputme[type=text]').each(function () {
        if(jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == ''){
            alert("Please fill all boxes");
            flag = false;
        }
    });
    return flag;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('#formId').submit(function() {

   $('input.inputme[type=text]').each(function (e) {

        if($(this).val()=='') {
            alert("Please fill all boxes");

            return false;
        }
    });

});
```